# Detect Video on webview and play it on exoplayer

Tags: android, webview, exoplayer

In UC browser it detects the video play on the website and plays that video on it's native player. Is there any way to do that. Is there any intent that fires when a video on web starts playing ? And how can we get that video data from web ?

UC Turbo :

[image]

Comment: You can use deeplink, pass the data through deeplink and pass in app and play video.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Comment: You didn't get me. - If a user opens a page which has a video in it then the webview should detect the video in page and play that video in native video player like exoplayer.

Comment: If webpage loading url of yoututbe it should come in 
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
//Here you can launch your youtube player
}

Comment: Any solution pls share?